# Using elemMatch for a nested condition query in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas  Student, User - where user can be class teacher or other designated persons.

**Student schema**

```
var StudentSchema = new Schema({
name : String,
.
.
.
owner: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
})
```

Now I want to group the students for a particular owner.(classTeacher)

I have written a server api route -method for this.

```
get ==> localhost:3000/api/---/user/:userId/students
```

userId is the `classTeacherid. = req.queryUserStudentsId`

```
exports.getUserStudents=function(req,res){

     Student
            .find()
            .select({            
                'owner': {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        _id: req.queryUserStudentsId
                    }
                }
            })
            .populate('owner')
    .exec(function(err, students) {

    };
```

This results in all the students. Not only those which belong to the given owner id.

Please let me know where I am wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: find() says find all documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`select`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) is used to select the fields to include in the returned docs.  You need to provide the `owner` filter to the `find` itself to filter the student docs to just those owned by `req.queryUserStudentsId`:

```
 Student.find({owner: req.queryUserStudentsId})
        .populate('owner')
        .exec(function(err, students) {
            ...
        });
```

You can omit the `.populate('owner')` call if you don't need to the full details of the owner.